# TextView load with delay and slow

Tags: ios, swift, textview, tableview

When I scroll down in tableview, the TextView load slow and scrolling has break.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].isDesc == false{
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("imagesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! imagesTableViewCell
            let indexA = self.arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text
            let path = "http://a"+indexA!
            let url = URL(string: path)
            cell.detailsImg.sd_setImage(with: url)
            return cell

        } 
            else {
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("imagesTableViewCellDesc", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! imagesTableViewCellDesc

            let textD = self.arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].text!
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.lineSpacing = 12
            let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
            cell.descText.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: textD, attributes:attributes)
                        cell.descText.textColor = UIColor.white
                        cell.descText.font = UIFont(name: (cell.descText.font?.fontName)!, size: 16)
                        cell.descText.textAlignment = .right


            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is `sd_setImage` defined?

Comment: Hello @Lamiya , when you are working with TableView , dont use Bundle.main.loadNibNamed , use this one dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Comment: I think the delay is happening because it looks as though you are re-loading the images every time you build a cell and not caching them anywhere. Depending on how many images you have, you might want to load some/all of them via some sort of asynchronous process when the table is initialised and then save them into your data model, then load them in from there, rather than create a http: request each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These below two lines are the root cause of your lagging. You are trying to use new `TableViewCell` everytime.

```
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("imagesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! imagesTableViewCell

let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("imagesTableViewCellDesc", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! imagesTableViewCellDesc
```

Hence to solve this you have to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your `if and else statement` like below

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imagesTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as imagesTableViewCell

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imagesTableViewCellDesc", forIndexPath: indexPath) as imagesTableViewCellDesc
```

and don't forgot to register your nib in `viewDidLoad()` like this

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "imagesTableViewCellDesc", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "imagesTableViewCellDesc")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "imagesTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"imagesTableViewCell")
```

As far as imageLoading is concerned, I don't think that it will lag your scrolling because I think you are using `SDWebImage` library which automatically caches images and works asynchronously.

Comment: using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier return nil cell

Comment: @Lamiya have you first register your nib in `viewDidLoad` ? If not please do it first

Comment: @Lamiya please check my edited code . Previously registering nib for imagesTableViewCell was not there. Please check it now carefully

Comment: I have two cell nibs, I registered both, one work fine but second return nil cell

Comment: @Lamiya Probably check the names of nibs while registering as your nib names are having almost samename. Meanwhile you can please post the code which you have written here for registering Nibs.